# How to get external xml data to load before MovieClip loads with AS 3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, load, event-listener

I have an AS3 project (main.FLA) that loads my XML data via an .as file (called projectData.as) utilizing the URLLoader function and tests for Event.COMPLETE and it's successful.  The issue is that I have a startup screen MovieClip on the stage (associated with an external as file called startUp.as) with dynamic textBox that needs the data in order to populate the text field but startUp.as loads BEFORE the XML loading projectData.as file. So startUp.as traces out a "In Startup" before the projectData.as file can trace out an "XML Loaded".

How can I force the projectData.as file to load the xml data before the startup.as calls for it?  Or, get the startUp.as file to wait for the projectData.as file to load the data before asking it to pull the text it needs? It would be redundant I think to make it load twice, but is there a way to for an order of execution in Flash?

Comment: Could you not move the portion of your `startUp.as` code to a separate method that you call after the XML file loaded completely? Ex: If you have your "In Startup" trace happening in the constructor, can you not place that part in a separate method to call it later?

Comment: Why don't you just wait until your xml's `Event.COMPLETE` event is fired before loading your startup screen?  or update your startup screen when the Event.COMPLETE occurs.  You don't show any code, so no one can give you specific help.